# Shared memory in shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have to create a library for memory allocators in shared memory in c. From my attempts I would have to open and map the shared memory in the beginning of every program that would use my library and passing the pointer to my malloc functions. Is it possible to open it only once inside the library? It is the only thing I don't understand how to do in this whole assignment

Comment: In todays operating systems each process has its own address space, so you have to map the shared memory at the start of every _process_ (not program or library).

Comment: So, every process would have to call shm_open, ftruncate and mmap and in the end shm_unlink Or should I only call ftruncate only if the shared memory has a size greater than 0. And I will have to pass a pointer to my malloc function

Comment: Your init function can save the handle in a static variable so you don't have to pass it to your malloc

Comment: Do you already have some code? Why not show it?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on application. If each program using library needs its own shared memory, every program has to call some init function of library which will allocate new shared memory.  If shared memory is required only once and library can do with it for every program later then a check on if it is allocated or not and if not allocate it will be enough.

Comment: If you're saying that a Linux .so in one process can open a shared memory segment on behalf of another, different process - that's simply wrong :(  If you're saying that every program that wants shared memory needs to open the memory segment for itself - but it doesn't matter whether "shm*" is called from the "main()" program or from the .so, then please re-word your response to make that clearer.